# iPhone map tiling issue on device and iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I have run into a very confusing situation with maps on the iPhone. Everything had been running without a hitch on a maps based app that I was developing, and then yesterday my device and the iOS simulators started exhibiting some bizarre behaviour where the tiles the app was fetching for the map did not line up with where they should be.
Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image]
[image]

This is happening on both my device (after a factory reset as well) and on the iOS simulator. I managed to fix the simulator by reinstalling Xcode, but this problem seems to be back! I can't for the life of me figure out what it could be.

I should note that I have tried clearing the map tiles cache and it would fix it for a while then the problem would start again.
Also I cleared the map tiles cache and then created an brand new MapKit app and the problem started again so I am sure it isn't my app causing it. It is happening also on the iOS 4 and 5 simulators.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For what it is worth- I happen to be visiting Australia from the US and have been noticing this issue on 5.0 when I'm on the cellular network. I'll see if it is persisting on my device once I'm back in the US.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Yea I thought it could be a caching issue on a network end. It's bizarre in that it only started occurring a day or two ago.

Comment: Yeah confirming the problem does not persist for me back in the US. Big thanks to TriPhoenix for the link.

Comment: Hi Nick, it seems that whatever the issue was has cleared up now, everything seems to be back to normal now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been quite some reports of people from the Japan area that this affects all devices in the area. Maybe this is the same thing in Australia as well. There is a lengthy apple discussion on https://discussions.apple.com/message/16630435 with affected people.

Comment: Thanks for the link! So it seems the problem is on the network end, I was getting worried I had somehow messed up the way MapKit cached tiles. I guess I'll just have to wait and see what happens. Thanks again!